# Filter a set of elements if they have ID as their attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `class selector` which will return about `20 elements`. Out of that, only `5 or 6` will have `id` as their attributes.

My area of interest is only those 5 or 6 elements.

How do I get elements with `ID` as their attributes? And this can contain any input, checkbox, selects or any form element.

Comment: You mean to say you have 5 of 20 which _have_ an id attr `id='something'`?

Comment: Yes. The rest of the elements do not have ids and I dont want them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute selector is sufficient:

```
$(".class-selector[id]")
```

This will select all elements that *have* the `id` attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is returning all the elements who id value is id="" as well. Can we filter it based on a starting values for the ids. All ids have the value starting with fieldb1 fieldb2 etc.

Comment: Starting value would be `[id^=fieldb]`

Answer (score 2):

You could use below selector to avoid `id=""` from selection.

```
$(":not([id='']).selector-class[id]")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery Attribute-Selector.

See: [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)